# При попытке сохранить данные из списка find_all , сохраняет их вместе с html заголовками, как сделать правильно?

Tags: python, html, парсер, beautiful-soup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import requests

not_filtred_information = list()
filtred_information = []
folder_list = []

opisanie = []
adres = []
price = []
infrastructure = []


home_url = 'https://spb.cian.ru/cat.php?deal_type=rent&engine_version=2&offer_type=flat&region=2&room1=1&type=4&p='


def urls_all_class(url, first_obj, class_obj):
    pass

count, con = 1, 0

while count < 2:
    url = home_url + str(count)
    req_url = requests.get(url)
    html_url = BeautifulSoup(req_url.text, 'lxml')

    price = html_url.find_all('div', class_='_93444fe79c--row--kEHOK')
    
    for i in list(price):
        if i.text.lstrip() == 'Только на Циан':
            continue
        not_filtred_information.append(i.text.lstrip())
    for i in not_filtred_information:
        folder_list.append(i)
        **При попытке сохранить данные в другой список, сохраняет вместе с html кодом**
        print(i)
        con += 1
        if con == 5:
            filtred_information.append(folder_list)
            folder_list = []
            con = 0
    print(type(filtred_information))
    print(len(not_filtred_information))
    time.sleep(2)
    count += 1
```

Comment: С какими заголовками? Приведите прямо в вопросе пример: у меня получается вот то-то, а я хочу, чтобы получалось вот то-то.